# Brackets.io: Is there a way to auto indent / format <html>

Tags: format, adobe-brackets, auto-indent

I am new to Brackets.io and thought I saw a shortcut key to auto indent/format HTML, however I cannot find a shortcut. Is there a shortcut or add-on that will do this for me?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/838323/388554

Answer (score 83):

I found an add-on for Brackets.io that uses auto-indent called Indentator.
It uses shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: Did you install the Indentator add-on? I just confirmed it works well on the current version of Brackets (1.8). First go to File > Extension Manager and search for Indentator. Upon completion of installation, use Crtl + Alt + i and it should work without issue.

Comment: This works fine, but only on the whole file, not on the selected code only

Comment: For macOS the shortcut is Ctrl + Option + I.

Comment: The author clearly missed the chance to name it as the **Indent-inator** (you read it in Doof's voice, didn't ya?)   ;)

Answer (score 59):

You can install an indentator package.

Click on <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Extension Manager...</kbd>.

Look for the search field and type: Indentator > Install

Once **Indentator** is installed, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Comment: how do you sent the indent width?

Comment: In the down-right corner -> click on "tab size" (changes to "spaces") then click on the value to change it. (taken from some Brackets repository issue)

Comment: After Indentator installation, menu is "Edit" > "Indent Document" (Ctrl + Alt + I)

Comment: Can you change the shortcut for this?

Answer (score 29):

[Beautify](https://github.com/drewhamlett/brackets-beautify) does a good job. It provides a "Beautify on save" option, so that you may use ctrl+s to reformate html, less, css, etc

Comment: Beautify does more than fixing indentation. Thanks for suggesting it!

Comment: It is in **edit** after installation and can be called with **Ctrl alt B**

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut key is ctrl+] to indentation and ctrl +[ to unindent

Answer (score 1):

The Identator plugin works to me in Brackets Release 1.13 versión 1.13.0-17696 (release 49d29a8bc) on S.O. Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing around with the preferences and added the following to my `brackets.json` file (access in Menu Bar: Debug: "Open Preferences File").

`"closeTags": {
    "dontCloseTags": ["br", "hr", "img", "input", "link", "meta", "area", "base", "col", "command", "embed", "keygen", "param", "source", "track", "wbr"],
    "indentTags": ["ul", "ol", "div", "section", "table", "tr"],
    }`

- `dontCloseTags` are tags such as `<br>` which shouldn't be closed.
- `indentTags` are tags that you want to automatically create a new
  indented line - add more as needed!
- (any tags that aren't in above arrays will self-close on the
  same line)