# Bash script Indentation in Brackets

Tags: bash, adobe-brackets

I tried multiple Brackets indentation extensions such as the one suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34489199/4828060), but they do not seem to work properly for Bash. Is there any extension available for Bash indentation?